# SageMaker TF 2.3 distributed training

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Using SageMaker v2.29.2 and Tensorflow v2.3.2 I'm trying to implement distributed training as explained in the following blogpost:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-parallel-customize-training-script-tf.html#model-parallel-customize-training-script-tf-23

However I'm having difficulties importing the smdistributed script.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import smdistributed.modelparallel.tensorflow as smp
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smdistributed.modelparallel.tensorflow as smp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smdistributed'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try with `Tensorflow 2.3.1` or `2.4.1` and let us know if it resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smdistributed is only available on the SageMaker containers. It is supported for specific TensorFlow versions and you must add:

```
distribution={'smdistributed': {
            'dataparallel': {
                'enabled': True
            }
        }}
```

On the estimator code in order to enable it